# IMAP server that handles its own accounts?

Tags: linux, email, imap

I have a Windows email server (not exchange) that I want to migrate away from. The Windows email server caused me some trouble in the past, and its time for it to go. I want to try a Linux email server.

I began setting up up a test server according to Ubuntu's [Setting up an Ubuntu System as an Email Server](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MailServer). After installing `postifx` and `courier`, I found I cannot add users to the `courier` imap service. The docs state I need to add users to the local machine's user database. See, for example, [Courier](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Courier). Re-running `dkpg` for the additional configuration options was not helpful.

Local system accounts kind of kills the whole idea of a migration, where I want to provide the admin password to both IMAP servers, and then run a tool to perform account creation on the new server, then IMAP reads from the existing server and IMAP writes to the new server. Additionally, it makes backups more complicated because mailbox data is sprayed all over the file system.

What Linux IMAP server fully supports itself without being tangled in other components? Ideally, I'm looking for something "that just works" without a lot of hassles. (This is why I went with the Windows email server in the first place).

Answer (score 1):

I've no experience with `courier`, but it seems that it has multiple auth modules, among them `authuserdb` module http://www.courier-mta.org/authlib/README_authlib.html#authuserdb

It basicaly use similar to `/etc/passwd` file format, but in another file.

There are also `authmysql`, `authpgsql`, `authsqlite` and `authldap` modules which can use databases or LDAP as authentifacation backend.

I've used `dovecot` as IMAP server and it seems to be quite similar in authentication features, see http://wiki2.dovecot.org/PasswordDatabase if you want to try `dovecot` instead.

Comment: Thanks F2nd. How about the mail message database? I'm trying to figure out how to back it up (I like weekly or daily backups). I want to avoid backing up the entire system when the only thing I care about are user accounts and their messages.